# SQL Server SUM DATEDIFF and NULL when looking at records between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, datediff, isnull

my problem is as follows:

I have a table (called table) with columns: ID, event, startdate, enddate

startdate goes from 1900-01-01 to current day, enddate does also. event is an arbitrary string, and each ID will start and end multiple events as time passes (but only one event at a time_.

Consider a case when we want to get records for dates between 1989-01-01 and 2000-01-01. We want to sum the differences between dates to get the total number of weeks each ID spends doing whatever event.

the probelm I have is that there ar epeople in the data who are still at some event I am interested in, so their enddate is null.

I currently am trying

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    ISNULL(enddate, 2000-01-01 sum(datediff(weeks, startdate, enddate)) AS wksdoingstuff 
WHERE 
    event IN ('something', 'somethingelse'. 'anotherthing') 
    AND BETWEEN 1989-01-01 AND 2000-01-01 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

What I am after:

I want rows of distinct IDs and each one will have a corresponding count of how many weeks they were at the events of interest

at the moment my code (not quite what i wrote there) gives me multiple rows for each ID summing each different period they've been at whatever event.

Comment: The code you've shown us is not even close to being able to run. Try to create a self-contained example of **runnable** code (I'd suggest populating a table variable with a few rows of data, actually querying from it with a `FROM` clause, fix whatever it is that's been mangled in the `ISNULL` line, etc)

Comment: Also, you need to give us a clear definition for what output you're looking for. `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*, and if we assume you meant `week` rather than `weeks`, you should be aware that it can return 1 for two dates that are only a day apart, if the first is Saturday and the second is Sunday. Is that the behaviour you want? Do *partial* weeks have to be taken into account here?

Comment: yes, partial behaviour is fine for the analysis, additionally i can always make it day to see if the data makes sense.

i'm aware my code as is won't run, i'm not at the computer to access the server, and when i am i do not have access to the internet so i need to write notes about the answer and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You need where end date is not null in your where clause then remove the isnull around it in the returned columns. You need to do a sum around the datediff psrt. Sorry I am on my phone so can't face typing out the code. If I remember I'll swing back when I have a keyboard later!

Also I agree that you should use dd (days) in your datediff otherwise you lose partial weeks. You can always cast it to a decimal amd divide the sum by 7.00

Comment: include is notnull in my where clause? but i want to arbitrarily say that the NULLS are the date 2000-01-01 because i'm basically counting how many weeks they've been at some grouping of events during a window of dates. 

I don't want to only add the non null dates, the people who have null end dates are still at the event and i want to count how many weeks they've been there.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute this..

```
SELECT 
    id, 
     sum(datediff(weeks, startdate, ISNULL(enddate, '2000-01-01')) AS wksdoingstuff 
WHERE 
    event IN ('something', 'somethingelse'. 'anotherthing') 
    AND BETWEEN 1989-01-01 AND 2000-01-01 
GROUP BY 
    id
```

Comment: Thank you very much